# unable to proceed protractor with cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I am very new to cucumber framework, i started scripting cucumber with protractor, when i try to run the cucumber. `conf.js` file , I have seen the following error message

> [17:07:35] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>
> [17:07:35] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
> UUUUU

Warnings:

```
1) Scenario: Login with valid userid and password # feature\test.feature:4
   ? Given I should be at the login page
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Given('I should be at the login page', function (callback) {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           callback(null, 'pending');
         });
       
   ? And I provide valid userid and password
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Given('I provide valid userid and password', function (callback) {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           callback(null, 'pending');
         });
       
   ? When I click on login button
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         When('I click on login button', function (callback) {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           callback(null, 'pending');
         });
       
   ? Then I should be able to login inside the Gmail
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Then('I should be able to login inside the Gmail', function (callback) {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           callback(null, 'pending');
         });
       
   ? And The title of web page should be Gmail main page
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Then('The title of web page should be Gmail main page', function (callback) {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           callback(null, 'pending');
         });
       

1 scenario (1 undefined)
5 steps (5 undefined)
0m00.000s
[17:08:31] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[17:08:31] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[17:08:31] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[17:08:31] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

my conf.js file is

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress : 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    getPageTimeout: 60000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
    framework: 'custom',
    // path relative to the current config file
    //frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
    specs: [
        '../feature/test.feature',
    ],

    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',

    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['../feature/step_definitions/stepDefinitions.js'],
        tags: false,
        strict: true,
        format: ["pretty"],
        dryRun: false,
        compiler: []
    },

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
    }
};
```

if anyone come across this problem, please suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: This means that you OR haven't implemented the JS code (the output is an example of how you write the glue code) OR you haven't added the JS file, in which you defined the glue code, to your protractor configuration file

Comment: I added .js file in my conf file  -  cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['../feature/step_definitions/stepDefinitions.js'],}